# lstat64 and stat64 undefined

Tags: c++, c, linux, ld, nm

When I set LD_BIND_NOW to 1, and then try to invoke my debug build application, it does not invoke due to undefined symbols lstat64, when I run nm and grep on "stat64":

```
U  lstat64@@libkernel32.so
U  stat64@@libgdiuser32.so
```

Where "libkernel32.so" and "libgdiuser32.so" are from a third party package and they do not contains any definition for lstat64.

However, the rls build works fine. When I run nm on it and grep "stat64"

```
U ___lxstat64@@GLIBC_2.2
U ___xstat64@@GLIBC_2.2
T lstat64
T stat64
```

I found that the debug version of kernel32.lib contains:

```
D stat64
D lstat64
U __xstat64
U __lxstat64
```

While the release version of kernel32.lib does not contain any reference to "lstat64" and "stat64"

In the code, we already includes "sys/stat.h", why the linker does not bring 
them from the glibc libs?

Or shall we use "__lxstat64" instead of "lstat64"?

Comment: Are you compiling on Windows?

Comment: No I am compiling on Linux.